# MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client crashes right after entering the correct password

Tags: mysql

MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client crashes right after entering the correct password. I have also checked in services and there is no problem there. I'm using windows

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: What does "crashes" mean exactly? Hangs? Returns to the command prompt? Displays an error message? Please be more specific. Also, how are you launching it: by clicking an icon, or by typing a command like `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\mysql.exe"`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This might be because MYSQL service is stopped.

1. Open search bar in windows and type services
   [image]
2. Open the services application and find MYSQL application.
   [image]
3. Click on start
4. Now open sql command line and try entering password

Answer (score 4):

It is because MySQL Server stop, may be you run another application that use the same port. Try to run MySQL Installer Community, and you will find the program that you have to reconfigure (blue text). Try to configure MySQL Server ant click Test Connection.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell with no debug output or error codes, but disabling ssl might do the trick:

```sh
mysql --ssl-mode=DISABLED --host=$MYSQL_HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, was looking through Google to find an answer and came here. Are you sure, that you provided MySQL password? The root cause of my problem was the fact, that I put the MySQL user instead of MySQL password (the root one). Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

That could mean that the password is failing. Check CapsLock key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel and uninstall MySQL Server only, you don't need to unstall the other MySQL files.
2. As mentioned [here](https://academind.com/tutorials/mysql-start-stop-uninstall-upgrade-server#stopping-a-running-server-windows), make sure you can see hidden folders and then delete the following folders:

   - C:\Program Files\MySQL
   - C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
   - C:\ProgramData\MySQL
   - C:\Users<your-username>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL
3. Reinstall MySQL Server Package only
4. Select another password (looks like the current password is the problem)
5. Come here and vote me up :)
6. Do something nice for someone else ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to reset root password should be uninstalling and installing MySQL Server from MySQL Installer.

1. Open MySQL Installer
2. Remove **only** MySQL Server
3. After the removal was completed, open MySQL Installer again
4. Add MySQL Server
5. Follow the usual steps and set a new password for root user.

Answer (score -1):

As was already noted by others, it looks like MySQL service was not running. On Windows, you need to go to Services > find MySQL > and start it.

You can change the startup type to Automatic to avoid that issue in the future
[image: change the MySQL startup type to Automatic on Windows]